# Recursive algorithm to evaluate postfix language in dafny

Tags: dafny

I have a sequence of this datatype

```
datatype Op = Operand(int) | Addition | Multiplication
```

I wrote the following evaluation function but it does not work. (I think the recursion is not correct but I do not know how to fix it.)

```
function method ValueOfPostFix(postfix: seq<Op>, index : nat): int
requires 0 <= index < |postfix|
decreases index
{
    match postfix[index]
    {
        case  Operand(x) => x   
        case Multiplication => if (index > 0) then ValueOfPostFix(postfix, index-1) * 
                                   ValueOfPostFix(postfix, index-1)
                                   else 0   
        case Addition => if (index > 0) then ValueOfPostFix(postfix, index-1) + 
                             ValueOfPostFix(postfix, index-1)
                             else 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a small failing example and start debugging.

Comment: From your question, it is difficult to understand what you think is broken about the code. I loaded it in Dafny and it type checked fine. Please include more information about what is wrong.